# SAS and text pointers - not reading all values

Tags: sas

```
data test;
    infile datalines missover;
    input @ "r1" r1
          @ "r2" r2
          @ "r3" r3
          @ "r4" r4;
    datalines;
    r4 34 r2 21 r3    r1 12
    r4 12 r2 19 r3    r1 76
    ;
run;
```

Why in the `test` data set I get only values of `r1` and the rest is `.`?

My desired output is:

```
r1    r2    r3    r4
--------------------
12    21    .     34
76    19    .     12
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading an example in [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000146292.htm#a000207336) I found the solution:

```
data test;
    infile datalines missover;
    input @'r1' r1
          @1 @'r2' r2
          @1 @'r3' r3
          @1 @'r4' r4;
    datalines;
    r4 34 r2 21 r3    r1 12
    r4 12 r2 19 r3    r1 76
    ;
run;
```

It is needed to go back to the beginnig of the line with `@1` because without this SAS keeps searching for the given strings from the last pointer location.